# I built up authentication in Laravel but unsuccessful

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In my project, I just need one authentication for admins and not for users and also have users table in my database but I don't want to use it in the authentication and in Admins table I want to use 'AD_AdminEmail' field as email and 'AD_AdminPassword' as authentication password and admins routes separated to management.php file.

These codes below not working and no errors but they redirect me to the login page again and Passwords in database hashed with laravel Hash::make() but Auth::attempt do not recognize it as hashed one and send a select query with plain password not hashed yet.

Here are My web route Codes:

```php
Route::get('/login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => function() {
    return view('LoginAndRegister');
}])->name('login');
Route::post('/ManagerLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@Authenticate');
```

Here are My LoginController Codes:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


    use App\Admin;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
        public function username()
        {
            return 'AD_AdminEmail';
        }
        
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
        
        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            return $request->only($this->username(), 'AD_AdminPassword');
        }

        protected function validateLogin(Request $Request){
            $this->validate($Request, [
                $this->username() => 'required|email,',
                'AD_AdminPassword' => 'required|min:8',
            ]);
        }

        public function Show()
        {
            return view('LoginAndRegister');
        }

        public function Authenticate(\Illuminate\Http\Request $Request)
        {  
            $AdminEmail = $Request->input('AD_AdminEmail');
            $AdminPassword = $Request->input('AD_AdminPassword');
            if (Auth::attempt([
                'AD_AdminEmail' => $AdminEmail,
                'AD_AdminPassword' => $AdminPassword
                ], false))
                echo 200 . "OK";
            else
                echo 400 . "Problem Found";
        }

        public function Logout()
        {
            Session::flush();
            Auth::logout();
            return back();
        }
    }
```

Here are My Admin model Codes:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = ['AD_AdminEmail', 'AD_AdminPassword'];
    protected $hidden = ['AD_AdminId', 'remember_token',];
    protected $primaryKey = 'AD_AdminId';
    protected $guarded = ['AD_AdminId'];
    protected $table = 'Admins';
    use Notifiable;

    public function getEmailAttribute() {
        return $this->AD_AdminEmail;
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($Value)
    {
    $this->attributes['AD_AdminEmail'] = strtolower($Value);
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->AD_AdminPassword;
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($Value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($Value);
    }
}
```

Here are My config>auth.php Codes:

```php
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'admins',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ], 
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

Comment: why not just use laravel auth method and add a boolean field named admin in the user table, then create a middleware who check if the user is an admin ?

Comment: Because in this project I don't have to do this and my users are signed up within android application and data are in the users table and my users table data going to be very much. So cannot do this.

Comment: This is happen for auth constructor

Comment: yes you can do that way, the number of user change nothing, and the fact that the user have to sign up on android app don't cause problem. what are you looking for exactly ? a back-end just for admin people on a website and for the user it's all on an app?

Comment: back-end just for admin people on a website and for the user it's all on an app? Yes Exactly.

Comment: This is happen for auth constructor - Where and Why and how to solve it??